# Can I resize to certain percentage by parent's height with keeping It's default ratio. (android)

Tags: android

I want to resize to certain percentage by parent's with keeping It's default ratio.

I want....

- Keep It's default ratio.
- Resize the height to a certain percentage by parents height.

---

I want to make a Button like this.
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb9Mh.png)

but i got this.
[click me 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t86Ty.png)

Here's my code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="..."
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@android:id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="..."
        android:textSize="..."
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    />
```

---

Comment: You can use constraintlayouts ratio related attribute to achieve this. Ratio can be combined with percentages.

Comment: @Nezih Yılmaz Thanks! I know 'app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio', but I don't know how to set value with percentages. I want to keep image's default ratio automacally. Please show me more.. T.T .. 

i tryed app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" with app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5", but it made just square..

Comment: Oh so you want to constraint image, not the button?

Comment: Umm.. I want set ratio automatically and certain percentage by parents height when I changing image resource....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your image is static, follow this path:

Find out ratio of your image by inspecting it. For example if the image is 10 x 25, its width : height ratio would be 2 : 5. Use this value on `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio`. You can then set a percentage value on one of dimensions and other will adjust itself to keep the ratio.

Comment: Thanks! I want to set`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` automatically when I change Image. Is that possible? Or I need to change ratio manually?

Comment: I set the image(100x200) to view and set `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:2"`. Then I change image(200x500).... Do I have to change it manually? or Can I change it automatically in xml?